# Firebase Storage Progress Bar

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

my question is really simple, I´m getting a value of -1 when I call `taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount()`, and therefore when I insert the sample code of the addOnProgressListener I get very weird progress updates.
Heres my complete code:

```
@Override
public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
  double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
  Log.d("Progress", "onProgress: The value of the max is: " + taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
  Log.d("Progress", "onProgress: The progress is: " + progress);
}
```

Please help guys! :(

Comment: it's look like, some error happening. Try to attach `onFailureListener` and print error to log

Comment: it does not show any error... do I have to add any metadata?

Answer (score 0):

I set the Upload Task with .putFile instead of .putStream, and it works, don´t know why but now it works! This is the code:

`UploadTasktask=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(Constants.Firebase_Storage).child("Test").putFile(uri, metadata)`

Answer (score 0):

cause it's a warning,I've seen someone who [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37109334) this issue cause it's not declared in the official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot.html#getBytesTransferred()) 
change your code to be like this:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")

public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
    Log.d("Progress", "onProgress: The value of the max is: " + taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
    Log.d("Progress", "onProgress: The progress is: " + progress);
}
```